# CLR Assembly Binding Cache

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

In the CLR Binder documentation there is this section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies#step2

It states that there is a cache of previous bindings.

Now, when does this cache get cleared. If I have a .netframework (4.7) web app running in IIS, does the stop and start of the app reset the cache? Or is the cache linked to the application pool? Basically, I updated a DLL to a new version in the bin but the old DLL is still being used. Checked the GAC and the DLL is definitely not there. So, now I am trying to understand exactly how this assembly binding works.

PS. If anyone has links to the source code, please post them

Comment: There is no assembly cache, it merely caches load failures so it can fail it again when another attempt is made to load the assembly.  This has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Read this again 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies#step2
Clearly states that if one has been loaded before then that resolution would be used.